# Error with stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I have declared a cursor to fetch max marks from table out side the procedure.
Fetching the value through that cursor inside procedure. 
But procedure returning zero.
Please help me finding the error.

I am using the following code.

```
Declare Cur Cursor for select max(marks) from stu

Procedure

Alter procedure DMM(@max int output)
as
open Cur
Fetch from Cur into @max
close Cur
```

Code used to execute the procedure

```
declare @max int
set @max = 0
exec @max = DMM @max out
select @max as MaxValue
```

Comment: @bluefeet: thanks for formatting.

Comment: Why even bother to create a cursor here, for retrieving a single value..... seems totally overkill and useless.... just use `SELECT @max = MAX(Marks) FROM dbo.stu` and you're done......

Comment: @marc - they are reusing variables as well so I will guess they are new to SQL

Comment: @Marc_s,@JNK: Yes i am new to SQL and learning about cursors. I tried doing that in the above way. cant i do it in that way?

Comment: @Marc_s: is that a wrong way of using cursor. If so please explain me the proper usage of cursors.
I am thankfull in advance.

Comment: @Pearl: the proper way is to **not** use cursors at all - if ever possible. Cursors are a horrible construct and really bad in many ways.

Comment: @marc_s: Oki thanks alot for u r suggestion and time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're problem is that you are using the same variable to store the output parameter as you are using to get the procedure's return code. Therefore, your return-code (`0`) is overwriting your output.

You should call your procedure as shown:

```
declare @max int
declare @returnCode int

set @max = 0
exec @returnCode = DMM @max out
select @max as MaxValue
```

Comment: Thanks alot. I understood the proper way if executing procedures.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are executing the procedure incorrectly, here's how you should do it:

```
declare @max int
set @max = 0
exec DMM @max output
select @max as MaxValue
```

Other than that I agree with marc_s, why use a cursor?